# Generating static class initializer using javapoet

Tags: java, code-generation, javapoet

Is it possible to generate static initializer using `javapoet`? See an example of what I'm trying to generate below:

```
class Foo {
    static int one = 1;
    static int two = 2;
    static int sum;

    static {
        sum = one + two;
    }
}
```

I tried adding static initializer as a constructor with `static` modifier:

```
TypeSpec.classBuilder("Foo")
    .addField(FieldSpec.builder(int.class, "one", Modifier.STATIC).initializer("1").build())
    .addField(FieldSpec.builder(int.class, "two", Modifier.STATIC).initializer("2").build())
    .addField(int.class, "sum", Modifier.STATIC)
    .addMethod(MethodSpec.constructorBuilder()
        .addModifier(Modifier.STATIC)
        .addCode("sum = one + two;")
        .build())
    .build();
```

But this produces `static Foo() { ... }` instead of `static {...}`, which is incorrect syntax.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @t0mppa, may be vice versa - that question is duplicate of mine (see the dates)

Comment: Well, the other one has an answer that is up-to-date. This one has an answer that gives the wrong idea, since it was fixed a while after. I don't mind which way things go, but should be left with one main question that has an up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with version 1.0, the latest at time of writing.

However, there is a pull request to address this (https://github.com/square/javapoet/pull/257) which will hopefully be merged before the next release (most likely version 1.1).